# How to make a rocket than achieve 40 miles in altitude

Tags: rockets, balloons

me and my friend are working on a design where a solid fuel rocket rides on a large weather balloon. The ball on would get 22 miles high before bursting, then the rocket would ignite at boat for 40 miles needed to pass the karman line.

My question is, what amount of thrust is needed to push a rocket that height, and what is it's burn time?

Note: I could split it to two stages

Comment: Welcome! Try to use good grammar..and you'll get a better response. Use as much detail as possible.

Comment: Detail, such as: what is your goal? Getting *something*, *anything*, even a BB, to 40 miles, and being able to verify it reached that altitude? Or to take some instrument, like a camera, and either radio back the images, or carry back a thumb drive with the images on them? This will tell a lot about what it will take.